# Pale text in PDF viewer

Tags: fonts, color

I have some problems with output text color in Acrobat Reader. I have to send my work to other people and I can't change their viewers. Text looks like (in Russian):

[image]

I'm using MikTeX 2.9 and `pdflatex` for generating output files.

Does anybody know, how to change display settings (may be I have to change font or anything else)?

Comment: That looks correct to me.  In my experience there is some variation between PDF viewers in how they, for example, antialias text, which can cause discrepancies in the perceived darkness of the fonts.  If you actually print the PDFs they should look correct.

Comment: Yes... I'd tried to print it. And all looks fine. But I have to show it in PC screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like a very light font, light meaning with thin strokes. Some viewers will render such fonts grayish, as a side effect of anti-aliasing. I don't think there's a whole lot you can do about it, unless you can find a heavier font.

Comment: Changed font to pscyr (Cyryllic font like "Times New Roman"). Now it looks better! Tanks a lot!!!

Comment: Note that Adobe Reader tends to have this problem with bitmapped fonts; they end up looking a lot lighter than Type1 fonts of comparable "color" when strokes widths are on the order of a display pixel or two.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there aren't many of us with a bakoma licence, so your `pscyr` solution is rather limited (it's not a free font).  there are a rather large number of fonts that offer cyrillic; for those of us that like the "times shape", the obvious choice would be `tgtermes`, part of the `fonts/tex-gyre` distribution on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tex-gyre).

(malyshev once offered me a bakoma licence, for free, but I declined -- as graciously as I could manage -- I almost never do actual "productive" work on any of my widnoze boxen.)

Answer (score 0):

In case MiKTeX produces pale pdf text when reading the pdf on-screen (no issue when printing), you should run `miktexinstallation\bin\updmap.exe` one single time on the machine you are compiling the latex file. 
Compile again and you will see that now the pdf text looks normal (proper truetype1 fonts embedded).

Comment: Please elaborate _why_ this helps.

Comment: I did this, now my PDF text looks like crap `:-(` I don't know how to undo this option now.